# Positioning of <MenuItems> under the Material-ui <Select> component

Tags: material-ui

By design, clicking on a material-ui `<Select>` component (or alternatively a `<TextField select>` component), causes the menu items to appear in a position which covers the originating Select/TextField element.

```
<Select ...>
  <MenuItem value={10}>Ten</MenuItem>
  <MenuItem value={20}>Twenty</MenuItem>
  <MenuItem value={30}>Thirty</MenuItem>
</Select>
```

Is it possible to override this positioning (whether with JSS or with a new composition) such that the menu items align themselves directly under the originating Select/TextField element?

Any guidance would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Material UI Select override Position in theme](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61370798/material-ui-select-override-position-in-theme)

Answer (score 85):

Use `MenuProps` attribute of `Select` element

```
<Select
    MenuProps={{
      anchorOrigin: {
        vertical: "bottom",
        horizontal: "left"
      },
      transformOrigin: {
        vertical: "top",
        horizontal: "left"
      },
      getContentAnchorEl: null
    }}
>
    <MenuItem value={10}>Ten</MenuItem>
    <MenuItem value={20}>Twenty</MenuItem>
    <MenuItem value={30}>Thirty</MenuItem>
</Select>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I was looking all over for this!

Comment: If your menu is too tall you may also need to use MenuProps.PaperProps.style.maxHeight to see these changes take any effect.

Comment: with anchorOrigin and getContentAnchorEl working fine but if added transformOrigin then it breaks again so I think if not required then dont to set transformOrigin property.

Answer (score 53):

#### Mui v5 :

The position of `<MenuItems>` is default under the Material-ui `<Select>` in Mui v5.

If want to change position, code sample :

[image: Edit TextField selectionStart]

#### Mui v4 :

1. Use `<Select>` and set menu items position:

```js
        <Select
          ...
          MenuProps={{
            anchorOrigin: {
              vertical: "bottom",
              horizontal: "left"
            },
            getContentAnchorEl: null
          }}
        >
```

2. Use `<TextField select>` and set menu items positon:

```
      <TextField
        ...
        select={true}
        SelectProps={{
          MenuProps: {
            anchorOrigin: {
              vertical: "bottom",
              horizontal: "left"
            },
            getContentAnchorEl: null
          }
        }}
      >
```

Code Sample :

[image: Edit TextField selectionStart]

Hope to help you !

Comment: Perfect example. The docs are a bit hard to find this sort of stuff in sometimes, so glad I was able to google it more quickly. Thanks.

Comment: In MUI 5, if the select list is too long to fit, the menu is repositioned over the select input like in MUI 4. Is there a way to set the anchor element for a select list like a dropdown menu so a long select will stay anchored to the select input?

Comment: I just figured out I need to set `MenuProps.PaperProps.style.maxHeight` as mentioned above. If the maxHeight can fit in the available space below the select input, the list will appear anchored to the lower left. If the maxHeight doesn't fit, the list will be shifted to fit.

Comment: working perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vjR2g.png)

If you want to play with positions, you will try it. MUI 5.11.6 version, popover component, the 2nd example.

Comment: You should consider adding an actual image description onto the image link so others will know what they're clicking the link to see.