# Material UI Select override Position in theme

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I want to override position of dropdown of selectfield in the theme (to not have to implement it on each select).

I have try:

```
createMuiTheme({
  overrides: {
    MuiSelect: {
      select:{
        MenuProps: {
          getContentAnchorEl: null,
            anchorOrigin: {
              vertical: "bottom",
                horizontal: "left",
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Position of dropdown is not override. 
I also try to replace `select` by `selectMenu` but nothing happen...

When I pass directly to compnent props, it's working:

```
<Select
  ...otherProperties, 
  MenuProps={{
    getContentAnchorEl: null,
    anchorOrigin: {
      vertical: "bottom",
      horizontal: "left",
    }
  }}
>
  ...childs
</Select>
```

How can I achived override this props for all select?

For informmation I am using:

```
"react": "^16.12.0",
"@material-ui/core": "^4.9.10", 
"typescript": "3.6.3",
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

The [overrides key](https://material-ui.com/customization/globals/#css) is for overriding styles. You should use the [props key](https://material-ui.com/customization/globals/#default-props) for defaulting props in the theme.

Here's the correct syntax:

```
const theme = createMuiTheme({
  props: {
    MuiSelect: {
      MenuProps: {
        getContentAnchorEl: null,
        anchorOrigin: {
          vertical: "bottom",
          horizontal: "left"
        }
      }
    }
  }
});
```

[image: Edit Select MenuProps in theme]

Related answer: [Is it possible to override material-ui components default props?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57359439/is-it-possible-to-override-material-ui-components-default-props/57360023#57360023)

Comment: First tanks for response. 
But with typescript the key accept in : 
  | 'root'
  | 'select'
  | 'filled'
  | 'outlined'
  | 'selectMenu'
  | 'disabled'
  | 'icon'
  | 'iconOpen'
  | 'iconFilled'
  | 'iconOutlined';

I was thinking same as you, but with typescript I can't.
Do you think I need to rise a bug on there github ?

Comment: Those are the valid CSS classes for MuiSelect within the `overrides` key of the theme. You need to use the `props` key of the theme as stated in my answer.

Comment: @user3805731 Here is a Typescript version of my sandbox (which doesn't look any different for the `createMuiTheme` portion): https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-lyskc?file=/demo.tsx